# Reactjs/Express App with private Data Server

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router

I'm just writing my first React/Express App. I have a data server api working fine on port 3001 talking to postgres. My web component on port 3000 makes requests to this and all is working fine locally. For deployment I have reverse proxied port 3000 to the required domain. Problem I have is that I would like to keep the server api private, but because the client makes the server request, it needs to be exposed too which I would prefer not to do.
Is there a simple deployment pattern I can use where the API requests are routed through the web server, not direct from client?

Comment: You won't ever avoid the requests being made by the client and being visible in the network traffic. If you wanted to mask the actual Data Server API from the client, you will need to write a proxy in Express to forward on the API requests to the data server. This would only really obscure the actual data server API though, users will still be able to access it via the proxy if they look at their network traffic and find the URL.

Comment: @SteveVaughan makes perfect sense thanks. Rather than proxy, I have CORS on the server, so if I set that to only accept the web domain will that reliably prevent 'unauthorised' access?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure it will, you may still find it is possible to use curl or similar to access the endpoints. A better approach, if possible for your data server would be to implement some form of authentication such as Basic Auth to protect from abuse. Something like https://github.com/LionC/express-basic-auth could be used. It really depends on what you are building though I guess.

Comment: @SteveVaughan that's great. CORS only as a first filter then Basic Auth over https to lock it down. It's not in need of mega security, I just don't want random extra traffic I didn't authorise. Thanks for your help.